# Cannot install Gdebi from Ub.Center nor Command - No Installation Candidate

Tags: 20.04, gdebi

Sorry. No online solution I can find to this error.....

Unable to install Gdebi on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS:
Trying - Ubuntu Center Search
- "No Application Found"
Trying - Command Line (after updating via Apt or Apt-get")
- "Package 'gdebi' has no installation candidate"

I'm stuck, and cannot install other problematic apps using gdebi.
Any help very much appreciated.

---

guy@xps3:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for guy:
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://eddie.website/repository/apt stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
guy@xps3:~$ sudo apt-get install gdebi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package gdebi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gdebi' has no installation candidate
guy@xps3:~$

Comment: Gdebi installed! - thanks you much user535733, accessing "universe" repository solved my issue. (3 hours of going in circles fixed in 5 minutes   ;)